# Heroku app crashing after 1 minute discord.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

My application kepps crashing on Heroku after 1 minute

```
020-04-12T15:26:27.936655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-12T15:26:31.855012+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-12T15:26:31.855028+00:00 app[web.1]: > vicibot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-12T15:26:31.855030+00:00 app[web.1]: > node main.js
2020-04-12T15:26:31.855031+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-12T15:26:32.416441+00:00 app[web.1]: working
2020-04-12T15:27:29.926204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Code:

```
const discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new discord.Client();
const port = process.env.PORT || 80
const token= '*Token*';
const prefix = 'vici!';
var servers = {};

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('dziala');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{
  let arg = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    switch(arg[0]){
        case 'ping':
            msg.channel.send('pong!');
            break;
}}
bot.login(token);
```

Simple Discord bot to answer to commands

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Why does your app *do*? Does it bind to the port Heroku tells it to?

Comment: share your code

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us your code. Please read [ask].

Comment: Edited. Sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know what happened there.
You need to add

````
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});```

into code
````